# Why aren't all homomorphic abelian groups isomorphic as well?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I don't think I understand isomorphism well enough.

Consider the albelian groups $G = (G_1, e_1, o_1 )$ and $H = (H_1, e_1, o_1 )$. Consider a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ that exists in case of these two groups.

Then consider the homomorphism $g:H\rightarrow G$ that is the inverse of the function $f$, i.e: $g=f^{-1}$.

Then $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are both identity mappings.

Does this not satisfy the conditions for isomorphism?

Comment: They do, by definition of isomorphism.

Comment: Umm, what are you referring to @Bernard

Comment: How do you know $g=f^{-1}$ exists, DaBamti? For example: $f(x)=2x$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$, but there is no $f^{-1}(1)$, so there is no inverse map.

Comment: To the last question: if there exist $f$ and $g$ satisfying the conditions, they're inverse isomorphisms. The question does not reflect the title.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That did cross my mind, but I'm too used to working with real numbers. So then if the inverse exists, one could say that the groups are isomorphic?

Comment: It's actually entirely true that for groups any bijective homomorphism is an isomorphism (this follows from the first isomorphism theorem), but a homomorphism need not be bijective.

Comment: @PVAL : no need to use first theorem, just see that $\varphi^{-1}(xy)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x')\varphi(y'))=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x'y'))=x'y'=\varphi^{-1}(x)\varphi^{-1}(y).$

Comment: @DaBamti There are actually some terrible homomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ that are neither onto nor $1-1$. But they are non-constructive.

Answer (score 0):

As a commentator already indicated, there does not always exist an inverse homomorphism.

For instance, consider the two groups $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $ under addition.  Clearly the former group can be embedded (Via a homomorphism) inside the second group, but there is not an onto inverse of that embedding.

An isomorphism is, by definition, a homomorphism with an inverse.